# Rails 3: Working Mongoid captcha exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, captcha

I've tried a handful of captchas for Rails 3 and none tend to play nicely with Mongoid. I don't need anything too fancy just something to do a quick human check.

How do you guys get one working with Mongoid? Are there alternative solutions?

Comment: This is a question for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's outside mongoid scope, but still applicable. Have a look at [Negative Captcha](https://github.com/subwindow/negative-captcha):

*Negative captchas create a form that has tasks that only bots can perform, but humans cannot. This has the exact same effect, with (anecdotally) a much lower false positive identification rate when compared with positive captchas. All of this comes without making humans go through any extra trouble to submit the form. It really is win-win.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use **simple-captcha** [v1rtual's](https://github.com/v1rtual) [branch](https://github.com/v1rtual/simple-captcha) with mongo support. Simple and clean setup and usage:

Just add to your Gemfile as:

```
gem 'wolcanus-simple_captcha', :require => 'simple_captcha', :git => 'git://github.com/v1rtual/simple-captcha.git'
```

Run generator:

```
rails generate simple_captcha
```

For Controller Based, add the following line in the file "app/controllers/application.rb":

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SimpleCaptcha::ControllerHelpers
end
```

In the view file within the form tags add this code:

```
<%= show_simple_captcha %>
```

and in the controller’s action authenticate it as

```
if simple_captcha_valid?
  do this
else
  do that
end
```

See the branch for more options: https://github.com/v1rtual/simple-captcha